# ERROR Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000) when starting gunicorn to run python app locally Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

When I run `heroku local web` I get the following error:

```
1:53:52 PM web.1 |  [2020-08-28 13:53:52 -0500] [1226] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
1:53:52 PM web.1 |  [2020-08-28 13:53:52 -0500] [1226] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
1:53:52 PM web.1 |  [2020-08-28 13:53:52 -0500] [1226] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
1:53:53 PM web.1 |  [2020-08-28 13:53:53 -0500] [1226] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
1:53:53 PM web.1 |  [2020-08-28 13:53:53 -0500] [1226] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
```

I am trying to run a Flask app locally through Heroku, and I am getting this error. This question is common, but I've tried several solutions and all have failed. When I run ps -ef | grep gunicorn or ps -ax | grep gunicorn, the only gunicorn process that shows up is the grep command that has just been run. I have also grepped for port 5000, nothing. Please let me know what files you would like to see. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent.  I've upgraded this comment to an answer.  Please consider accepting.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the standard dev server which is running in another process locally.

`grep gunicorn` which you used in both of your debug commands wouldn't show this, and the output of `ps -ax` and `ps -ef` may not show ports, unless part of the originally launched command.

Instead try looking for what's listening if you have `sudo` privileges:

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P  | grep 5000
```